# Yeoman Grunt Build ... Wrong Font Dir

Tags: laravel, gruntjs, yeoman

Im really new to Yeoman, I just tried it yesterday and I'm not sure where to do some configurations.
My problem is that the minified vendor CSS (AKA Bootstrap) is trying to get the fonts from the ROOT of my server

my structure is like this:

Here are my production files

> htdocs/laravel/public/dist

the fonts are located in

> dist/fonts

BUT, if I look in the minified vendor css file, the fonts url is set to

> /bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/

which means is looking in the htdocs folder, and I know it this because I copied my assets in the htdocs and tn works...

How do I configure Grunt so the url points to the dist/fonts and Not to the root???
I've checked the Gruntfile.js and I can't find where is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the exact same problem yesterday.

I found out that this pull request is fixing the issue:
https://github.com/cebor/generator-angular/commit/c6d5ee67e108a0699f95c78702cb1939233226a8

What I did to fix it in my project was commenting out the following lines of code.  According to the pull request this cssmin does nothing but replace relative paths by absolute paths.

```
// The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
cssmin: {
  options: {
    root: '<%%= yeoman.app %>'
  }
},
```

The a grunt build uses the correct path, which is "../fonts"